# How to read a .txt file with a button (inside a condition) in android studio?

Tags: android, text, readfile

It could seem a simple question, but I can't find the answer everywhere. I know how to read a text file.. but I'd like to read it only if a button is pressed under a if-statament.. this is the code where I come from...

```
     @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);
    TextView textview1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textviewone);



    Bundle extradata1 = getIntent().getExtras();
    String textString = extradata1.getString("text");
    if (textString.equals("firsttext"))
    {

        String texttxt = "";
        StringBuffer sbuffer = new StringBuffer();
        InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.file);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        try {

            while ((texttxt = reader.readLine()) !=null){
                sbuffer.append(texttxt + "n");

            }

            textview1.setText(sbuffer);
            is.close();


        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Now.. this obviously reads it without the button.. what if I want to read the file only if a button is pressed? I'm not really sure of where to put the intent.

Answer (score 0):

Implement this:

```
  Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.your_button_id);
  button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {
    if (textString.equals("firsttext")) {

     String texttxt = "";
     StringBuffer sbuffer = new StringBuffer();
     InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.file);
     BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

     try {

      while ((texttxt = reader.readLine()) != null) {
       sbuffer.append(texttxt + "n");

      }

      textview1.setText(sbuffer);
      is.close();


     } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
     }
    }
   }
  });
```

Check [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html) also.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can achieve this.

Make `textString` as class varibale.

1. Add a `Button` in your layout file.

   ```
   <Button
       android:id="@+id/button"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:text="Read File"
       android:textAllCaps="false"/>
   ```
2. Create a reference for this button in class file.

   ```
   Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
   ```
3. Add `click listener` for this button and implement `onClickListener` interface.

   ```
   button.setOnClickListener(this);
   ```
4. Implement `onClick()` method.

   ```
   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {

   switch (view.getId()) {
       case R.id.button:
           if (textString.equals("firsttext")){
               String texttxt = "";
               StringBuffer sbuffer = new StringBuffer();
               InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.file);
               BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

               try {

                   while ((texttxt = reader.readLine()) !=null){
                       sbuffer.append(texttxt + "n");

                   }

                   textview1.setText(sbuffer);
                   is.close();


               }catch(Exception e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
           }
           break;
   }
   }
   ```

Comment: I need the if-statament because it needs to be related to a previous activity extradata. Looks like the connetction will it be lost with this method.

Answer (score 0):

```
Please Try below code 

 public class DemoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        Button btn;
        TextView txt;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

            /**
            * get your bundle text value */
            Bundle extradata1 = getIntent().getExtras();
            String textString = extradata1.getString("text");

            btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn); // Your Button
            txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView); //Your Textview

            //OnClick handle of button
            btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    if (textString.equals("firsttext")) {

                        String texttxt = "";
                        StringBuffer sbuffer = new StringBuffer();
                        InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.file);
                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

                        try {

                            while ((texttxt = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                                sbuffer.append(texttxt + "n");
                            }

                            txt.setText(sbuffer);
                            is.close();

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: InputStream is = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.file);

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. It gives me errors in the: "this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.file)"

Comment: try to this  
InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.file);

Comment: Ok, now it does not istantly give me error! but the App crashes when i open the page. Anyhow thank you!